# How do I run a non-ASCII/Unicode shell command from Ruby on Windows?

Tags: ruby, unicode, character-encoding

I cannot figure out the proper way to encode a shell command to run from Ruby on Windows. The following script reproduces the problem:

```
# encoding: utf-8

def test(word)
  returned = `echo #{word}`.chomp
  puts "#{word} == #{returned}"
  raise "Cannot roundtrip #{word}" unless word == returned
end

test "good"

test "bÃd"

puts "Success"

# win7, cmd.exe font set to Lucinda Console, chcp 65001
# good == good
# bÃd == bÃƒd
```

Is this a bug in Ruby, or do I need to encode the command string manually to a specific encoding, before it gets passed to the cmd.exe process?

**Update**: I want to make it clear that the problem is not with reading the output back into Ruby, its purely with sending the command to the shell. To demonstrate:

```
# encoding: utf-8

File.open("bbbÃd.txt", "w") do |f|
  f.puts "nothing to see here"
end

filename = Dir.glob("bbb*.txt").first
command = "attrib #{filename}"

puts command.encoding

puts "#{filename} exists?: #{ File.exists?(filename) }"
system command
File.delete(filename)

#=>
# UTF-8
# bbbÃd.txt exists?: true
# File not found - bbbÃƒd.txt
```

You can see that the file gets created correctly, the `File.exists?` method confirms that Ruby can see it, but when I try to run the `attrib` command on it, its trying to use a different filename.

Comment: What do you get if you add `puts returned.encoding` after the shell command?

Comment: `UTF-8`. All of the ruby strings are UTF-8. It has something to do with the encoding of the command sent to cmd.exe.

Comment: Same problem here. There has to be a way to get Unicode to the shell...

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the environment variable `LC_CTYPE` like this:

```
 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

Set this globally in the command shell or inside your Ruby script:

```
ENV['LC_CTYPE']='en_US.UTF-8'
```

Comment: That didn't solve it for me. Does my script above work for you with that change?

Comment: apparently, it is not possible with cmd.exe. [see this](http://superuser.com/a/271862)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using drag-and-drop in windows.
When I dropped a file having unicode characters in it's name the unicode characters got replaced by question marks.
Tried everything with encoding, changing the drophandler etc.
The only thing that worked was creating a batch file with following contents.

```
ruby.exe -Eutf-8 C:\Users\user\myscript.rb %*
```

The batch file does receive the unicode characters correctly as you can see as you do an `echo %*` first followed by a `pause`

I needed to add the `-Eutf-8` parameter to have the filename come in as UTF-8 in the script itself, having the following lines in my script were not enough

```
#encoding: UTF-8
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

Hope this helps people with similar problems.